# Getting frame data in a layer using actionscript 3.0 for flash animation

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, animation

How do I use actionscript 3.0 to get all of the image data in a frame of flash animation? This seems like a very basic thing, but I can't find anything on it.

Comment: Could you please elaborate your questions..

Comment: You want screen grabs (pixel data) or shape information (vectors data)? Also _"to get **all** of the image data"_ makes it sound like you only got part of it, is there something we should know about what you tried already?

Comment: Just pixel data. Say I have a frame and I want to know all of the pixel colors. In matlab, you can take an image and loop through all of the pixels. There must be something like that in actionscript 3.0.